# Получить имя слоя из кода Pyqt5

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, qt5

У меня есть метод, в котором я перебираю все объекты и мне бы хотелось, к примеру перебрать все объекты определенного слоя, для этого мне нужно знать или его имя или его id, логичнее использовать имя, тк id легко может поменяться и придется все менять, поэтому я написал данный тестовый метод:

```
def set_wiget(self, name=None):
        q = Queue()
        q.put(self.ui.verticalLayout)
        while q.qsize() != 0:
            l = q.get()
            for j in range(l.count()):
                obj = l.itemAt(j)
                if type(obj) == PyQt5.QtWidgets.QWidgetItem:
                    pass
                else:
                    if obj.name() == name:
                        q.put(obj)
```

Но я никак не могу получить имя слоя, к примеру с обычными виджетами это работает с помощью метода `nameObject()`, для слоя же ничего не подходит
Подскажите пожалуйста, как я могу получить имя слоя при переборе всех объектов

Comment: Пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему и лучше расскажите что вы хотите сделать. и что такое слой.

Comment: Любой класс `Qt` наследуется хотя бы от `QObject`, а у него есть метод `objectName`.